# echo >> style appending, but to the beginning of a file

Tags: shell, unix

Is there any nice trick in UNIX shell to append lines to the beginning of a file? E.g. akin to

```
   echo "Foobar" >> file.txt
```

... but instead new lines would prepend the existing ones?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In 2 steps:

```
content=$(cat file.txt) # no cat abuse this time
echo -en "foobar\n$content" >file.txt
```

Comment: Can still avoid the `cat`:  

`content="$(<file.txt)"`

Comment: @MarkReed has an interesting suggestion that works in bash, but not in dash.  I believe this is another example of the bash behavior not conforming to the language spec, since `<file.txt` should not generate any output.  Interesting that  `<file.txt` produces output in zsh, but not in bash.

Comment: Note that setting content this way will discard all trailing whitespace from the file, including the final newline.

Comment: @WilliamPursell - not if you put double-quotes around it, as I did in my version above.  Also, `<file.txt` doesn't produce any output by itself. `$(<file.txt)` is a special form, not regular command substitution; in particular, note that `\`<file.txt\`` doesn't do anything.

Comment: @MarkReed It is called process substitution, and has existed in some de-facto standard shells like ksh since ksh88.  It is not a POSIX-compliant shell requirement, i.e., POSIX shells (e.g., /bin/sh) do not have to support it.

Comment: @jimmcnamara: No, `<(...)` is process substitution.  `$(<...)` is file-contents-substitution.

Answer (score 6):

This is nonstandard, but if your sed supports -i you can do:

```
sed -i '1i\
Foobar' file.txt
```

Comment: @dogbane  Omitting the escaped newline works in some sed, but not all.  Many sed will choke if it is left out.

Answer (score 3):

I'd keep it simple. The easiest and probably fastest solution is straightforward:

```
(echo "Foobar"; cat file.txt) >tmpfile
cp tmpfile file.txt
rm tmpfile
```

If it doesn't matter that file.txt's inode changes, replace the "cp" by "mv". A solution significantly faster than this is not possible, because Unix filesystem semantics don't support prepending to a file, only appending.

Comment: Rather than cp and remove, why not just `mv tmpfile.txt file.txt`?

Comment: 'If it doesn't matter that `file.txt`'s inode changes, replace the "cp" by "mv"'

Comment: How often do you really care about the inode changing?

Comment: Depends. Changing the inode means creating a whole new file, so the permissions, and any other data associated with the inode of the existing file, such as SELinux data, extended attributes etc, will be lost. Also if another process, such as tail(1), has the original file open, it won't see the new data if you create a new file rather than alter the original file.

Comment: Fair points, though `tail` does have the `-F` option for following the file even if the inode changes.  Of course, an `mv` does not involve rewriting the files contents, so if the file is very large, using `mv` instead of `cp` will do half the I/O.